# What does the request for , or } at the end of a JSON file mean?

Tags: json, spotify

This file contains information about Ed Sheeran songs. I have gathered the data with the spotify api.

```
{
"0":{"name":"I Don't Care (with Justin Bieber)", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 101.956, "key": 6, "loudness": -5.041, "danceability": 0.798, "speechiness": 0.0442, "uri": "spotify:track:0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "id": "0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "acousticness": 0.0912, "valence": 0.842, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "liveness": 0.0894, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "energy": 0.675, "duration_ms": 219947, "instrumentalness": 0},
"1":{"name":"Beautiful People (feat. Khalid)", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 92.977, "key": 5, "loudness": -8.113, "danceability": 0.64, "speechiness": 0.187, "uri": "spotify:track:70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "id": "70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "acousticness": 0.124, "valence": 0.548, "mode": 0, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "liveness": 0.0802, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "energy": 0.648, "duration_ms": 197867, "instrumentalness": 0},
"2":{"name":"Perfect", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 95.05, "key": 8, "loudness": -6.312, "danceability": 0.599, "speechiness": 0.0232, "uri": "spotify:track:0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "id": "0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "acousticness": 0.163, "valence": 0.168, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 3, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "liveness": 0.106, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "energy": 0.448, "duration_ms": 263400, "instrumentalness": 0},
"3":{"name":"South of the Border (feat. Camila Cabello & Cardi B)", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 97.986, "key": 9, "loudness": -6.376, "danceability": 0.857, "speechiness": 0.0824, "uri": "spotify:track:4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "id": "4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "acousticness": 0.148, "valence": 0.668, "mode": 0, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "liveness": 0.0865, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "energy": 0.621, "duration_ms": 204467, "instrumentalness": 0},
"4":{"name":"Shape of You", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 95.977, "key": 1, "loudness": -3.183, "danceability": 0.825, "speechiness": 0.0802, "uri": "spotify:track:7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "id": "7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "acousticness": 0.581, "valence": 0.931, "mode": 0, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "liveness": 0.0931, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "energy": 0.652, "duration_ms": 233713, "instrumentalness": 0},
"5":{"name":"Photograph", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 107.989, "key": 4, "loudness": -10.48, "danceability": 0.614, "speechiness": 0.0476, "uri": "spotify:track:6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "id": "6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "acousticness": 0.607, "valence": 0.201, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "liveness": 0.0986, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "energy": 0.379, "duration_ms": 258987, "instrumentalness": 0.000464},
"6":{"name":"Thinking out Loud", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 78.998, "key": 2, "loudness": -6.061, "danceability": 0.781, "speechiness": 0.0295, "uri": "spotify:track:1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "id": "1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "acousticness": 0.474, "valence": 0.591, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "liveness": 0.184, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "energy": 0.445, "duration_ms": 281560, "instrumentalness": 0},
"7":{"name":"Happier", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 89.792, "key": 0, "loudness": -7.355, "danceability": 0.522, "speechiness": 0.0288, "uri": "spotify:track:2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "id": "2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "acousticness": 0.536, "valence": 0.236, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "liveness": 0.135, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "energy": 0.385, "duration_ms": 207520, "instrumentalness": 0},
"8":{"name":"Galway Girl", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 99.943, "key": 9, "loudness": -3.374, "danceability": 0.624, "speechiness": 0.1, "uri": "spotify:track:0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "id": "0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "acousticness": 0.0735, "valence": 0.781, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "liveness": 0.327, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "energy": 0.876, "duration_ms": 170827, "instrumentalness": 0},
"9":{"name":"Castle on the Hill", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 135.007, "key": 2, "loudness": -4.868, "danceability": 0.461, "speechiness": 0.0989, "uri": "spotify:track:6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "id": "6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "acousticness": 0.0232, "valence": 0.471, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "liveness": 0.14, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "energy": 0.834, "duration_ms": 261154, "instrumentalness": 1.14e-05}
}
```

The error that I'm getting says a "," or "}" was expected at the end of the file.

Comment: do not use api tag. Use instead spotify, because api tag is not recommend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a curly brace after each song. You are not closing both data open braces, you are just closing the index braces. Here is the correct json

```
{
"0":{"name":"I Don't Care (with Justin Bieber)", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 101.956, "key": 6, "loudness": -5.041, "danceability": 0.798, "speechiness": 0.0442, "uri": "spotify:track:0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "id": "0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "acousticness": 0.0912, "valence": 0.842, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "liveness": 0.0894, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/0hVXuCcriWRGvwMV1r5Yn9", "energy": 0.675, "duration_ms": 219947, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"1":{"name":"Beautiful People (feat. Khalid)", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 92.977, "key": 5, "loudness": -8.113, "danceability": 0.64, "speechiness": 0.187, "uri": "spotify:track:70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "id": "70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "acousticness": 0.124, "valence": 0.548, "mode": 0, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "liveness": 0.0802, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/70eFcWOvlMObDhURTqT4Fv", "energy": 0.648, "duration_ms": 197867, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"2":{"name":"Perfect", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 95.05, "key": 8, "loudness": -6.312, "danceability": 0.599, "speechiness": 0.0232, "uri": "spotify:track:0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "id": "0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "acousticness": 0.163, "valence": 0.168, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 3, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "liveness": 0.106, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v", "energy": 0.448, "duration_ms": 263400, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"3":{"name":"South of the Border (feat. Camila Cabello & Cardi B)", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 97.986, "key": 9, "loudness": -6.376, "danceability": 0.857, "speechiness": 0.0824, "uri": "spotify:track:4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "id": "4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "acousticness": 0.148, "valence": 0.668, "mode": 0, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "liveness": 0.0865, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/4vUmTMuQqjdnvlZmAH61Qk", "energy": 0.621, "duration_ms": 204467, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"4":{"name":"Shape of You", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 95.977, "key": 1, "loudness": -3.183, "danceability": 0.825, "speechiness": 0.0802, "uri": "spotify:track:7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "id": "7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "acousticness": 0.581, "valence": 0.931, "mode": 0, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "liveness": 0.0931, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3", "energy": 0.652, "duration_ms": 233713, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"5":{"name":"Photograph", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 107.989, "key": 4, "loudness": -10.48, "danceability": 0.614, "speechiness": 0.0476, "uri": "spotify:track:6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "id": "6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "acousticness": 0.607, "valence": 0.201, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "liveness": 0.0986, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6fxVffaTuwjgEk5h9QyRjy", "energy": 0.379, "duration_ms": 258987, "instrumentalness": 0.000464}},
"6":{"name":"Thinking out Loud", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 78.998, "key": 2, "loudness": -6.061, "danceability": 0.781, "speechiness": 0.0295, "uri": "spotify:track:1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "id": "1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "acousticness": 0.474, "valence": 0.591, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "liveness": 0.184, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg", "energy": 0.445, "duration_ms": 281560, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"7":{"name":"Happier", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 89.792, "key": 0, "loudness": -7.355, "danceability": 0.522, "speechiness": 0.0288, "uri": "spotify:track:2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "id": "2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "acousticness": 0.536, "valence": 0.236, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "liveness": 0.135, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/2RttW7RAu5nOAfq6YFvApB", "energy": 0.385, "duration_ms": 207520, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"8":{"name":"Galway Girl", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 99.943, "key": 9, "loudness": -3.374, "danceability": 0.624, "speechiness": 0.1, "uri": "spotify:track:0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "id": "0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "acousticness": 0.0735, "valence": 0.781, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "liveness": 0.327, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/0afhq8XCExXpqazXczTSve", "energy": 0.876, "duration_ms": 170827, "instrumentalness": 0}},
"9":{"name":"Castle on the Hill", "data": {"type": "audio_features", "tempo": 135.007, "key": 2, "loudness": -4.868, "danceability": 0.461, "speechiness": 0.0989, "uri": "spotify:track:6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "id": "6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "acousticness": 0.0232, "valence": 0.471, "mode": 1, "time_signature": 4, "track_href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "liveness": 0.14, "analysis_url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT", "energy": 0.834, "duration_ms": 261154, "instrumentalness": 1.14e-05}
}}
```